# Control the application from control center in iOS

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, control-center

I am using AVAudioPlayer in my iOS application and the following functionalities have been given.

**1. Play
2. Pause
3. Next
4. Previous**

My requirement is, I want to give these functionalities from control center. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Control Center uses same API as lock screen. The audio controls appear on lock screen when a properly configured `AVAudioSession` is active. In addition to that you need to use `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` API to set correct media information.

```
MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc]initWithImage:albumImage];

[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo = @{ 
    MPMediaItemPropertyTitle : aSong.songTitle,
    MPMediaItemPropertyArtist : aSong.artistName,
    MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork : artwork,
    MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate : 1.0f
};
```

See the questions below for more information:

- [Why do the Lock Screen audio controls disappear when I pause AVAudioPlayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892151/why-do-the-lock-screen-audio-controls-disappear-when-i-pause-avaudioplayer)
- [AVAudioPlayer on Lock Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363058/avaudioplayer-on-lock-screen)